# Cannot connect Nexus One Phone to Android adb

Tags: android, nexus-one

I am running Android SDK 2.2 and am trying to get the adb to connect to the Google Nexus One phone. Its a new phone, shipped straight from Google - haven't installed any apps on it yet.
(I have Windows XP)
Here is what I have done so far:

- Followed the instructions on setting up the device for development as given on the Android Developer's site:
  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html
- added android:debuggable="true" to my application manifest
- USB debuggable is checked on the phone
- downloaded the Device Drivers For Windows Revision 3 (this supports Nexus One phones)
- Went through the Hardware Installation wizard to install the device - the device shows up as "Android Composite ADB Interface".

When I run adb devices on the shell, the device appears for a moment, then disappears.
On the Eclipse console, I get the following message:
[2010-11-13 11:54:42 - DeviceMonitor]Failed to start monitoring

I have rebooted the pc several times, uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers several times, but I get the same error each time. As I was researching this problem, someone had recommended rebooting the phone. I am a bit confused by that - is that a soft or hard reboot? Do I just power the phone off/on and is there something more complex involved? Do I have to hard reboot it to reset to factory version - even though its brand new?

Has anyone run into a similar problem? Any help on this would be great. 
I can't test my application on the device if the adb cannot view the device. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: "Do I just power the phone off/on and is there something more complex involved?" -- if somebody tells you to reboot your phone, a simple power-off/power-on (note: not just putting the phone to sleep) will suffice.

Comment: I had very similar problem with Nexus one (although happened with other devices too). For some reason it didn't work when I used a keyboard USB hub to connect to the device but started to work correctly when I started to connect the USB cable to directly yo my laptop. It could also be a faulty USB cable. I have one (cheap) cable that works for recharging but does not work for debugging. Worth checking the cable.

Answer (score 13):

I had this same problem. To get it working, do the following:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open Task Manager and kill the `adb.exe` program.
3. Re-open Eclipse (Eclipse will automatically restart the adb.exe service)

Run `adb devices` from a command prompt and you should see something like the following:

```
C:\> adb devices
List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF        device
```

Of course, I'm assuming you have your phone plugged into your computer.

Comment: I also restarted my tablet, and it solved this problem for me. Thanks

Comment: Unless `adb` really isn't responding, you can also just execute `adb kill-server`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like something is killing the service as soon as it starts. Try disabling any anti-virus and running `adb devices` again. You can also check your system logs for errors - run `compmgmt.msc` and check the Event Viewer's logs.

> When I run adb devices on the shell, the device appears for a moment, then disappears

Do you mean Windows' command shell `cmd.exe`? The output of 'adb devices' doesn't update itself, it should just print out what's currently connected then terminate.

Comment: I tried the above suggestions - ran compmgmt.msc - nothing shows up in the Event Viewer Logs. Also tried rebooting the phone (powered it off and on). Still the same error message in the Eclipse console - adb still doesn't see the device.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing here worked for me. And you know what? I plugged it to my USB 3.0 port.

**Just plug it to regular USB 2.0 and it'll work.**

Comment: Changing which USB port it was plugged into worked for me.  However I don't think it was because it was plugged into a USB 3.0 port.

Comment: I'm not the only person who reported it. I don't know what is the exact reason, but searching for the solution I found several developers having problem with usb 3. Some people have problems with their cables also, so the reasons may be mixed

Comment: I had a similar problem, running Linux Mint Debian Edition. Using one particular USB port, I cannot connect to the phone, `adb` gives the serial number as `????????????` and says `no permissions`. With other ports it works. All my ports are USB 2.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you jst need upgrade your usb driver, follow this ref link, after upgrading you need to uncheck USB debugging, disconnect cable from device and then check USB debugging and connect cable to device again. this'll solve your problem..
[link text](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Do the following:

Plug your phone into your computer and:

> 1. Run the command prompt.
> 2. Go to the tools location of the android sdk.
> 3. run 'adb kill-server'
> 4. then run 'adb start-server'.

Turn off COMODO Firewall and Defense+ module

Answer (score 0):

I got my Nexus One on Windows 7 64 bit going by following these instructions:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Note that the directory has changed to /extras/google/usb_driver.

You know that you need to do this if you go to control panel->devices and printers and show properties on the device, and there's no driver shown.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the task manager by `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`
- In the Processes select `adb.exe` and Click the End process Button.
- Now close the eclipse and restart it again.

  This worked for me. Hope this would work for you as well.