# Constantly getting ...DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring

Tags: android, device, monitor, dalvik

I find that after running or debugging my application a few times using eclipse, that I get the above output in my console (in red) and I get no feedback from Dalvik as to the connection status to my phone is going. My application will still debug etc. I just get nothing useful in my Console.

Any ideas how to fix this? It appears intermittent. It starts doing it after a few minutes, continues to do it for quite a while and occasionally goes away again. This has happened on my last laptop and now on my new laptop with a completely fresh install etc.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7622641/8524) solved it for me

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit; but maybe 2 or 3 times during the day I get this same error. I tried the reboot thing, which sometimes worked, sometimes didn't.

I have found the fix to be:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Unplug USB
3. Open task manager and find the "adb.exe *32" and End Task
4. Open Eclipse (not done yet)
5. "Clean All" (not just project)
6. Then build the project (for me, just building the project works)
7. Plug USB back in and there ya go!

Always works for me. If anyone knows of an update to something I can download to avoid doing this all the time, I'd love to know!

Comment: tks, killing the adb.exe did it. first year of development is spending 10 minutes writing code and the rest of the day researching stack overflow for a new cryptic error message and doing odd fixes like this one. I only clean as a last resort however, as that can initiate the dreaded "R not found" error on all lines of codes involving a resource.

Comment: All I had to do was kill adb.exe as instructed above. Thanks.

Comment: I only needed steps 1-3.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem -
Try to use a different USB port.
From my experience, the USB connections on the PC front are not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Year almost 2018 I just had same problem which doubled my gray hairs. It turned out my test phone **Samsung Galaxy S6 does not like the USB ports on my Apple Thunderbolt Display**. I just plugged the USB cable directly to my Mac Pro and it worked right away. Funny thing is my Google Pixel Phone never complains about the USB port on Thunderbolt.

Comment: the solution,connect the usb in other port WDF!

Comment: 2020, the same solution worked - one USB port was disliked, one not and complete lack of any useful error message....

Answer (score 1):

To keep the error message from showing up I did the following on Eclipse 3.7:

- Window->Preferences
- On the left side tree select Android->DDMS
- In the DDMS settings window choose logging level "Assert"
- Click "Apply"

Comment: This will just hide the problem

Answer (score 1):

You may have to kill the deamon and restart it. Following are the steps;

1. open a command prompt and locate the SDK's platform tools folder. E.g.:- cd c:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools
2. then execute "adb kill-server" command. You will see the disconnected icon in run configuration panel is now cleared.
3. then again execute "adb start-server" command.
4. Then try running the device, if it doesn't work try restarting the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

restart your dev machine, worked for me :)

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, but resetting only occasionally helps and for a short time, if at all.

Comment: Switch to IntelliJ IDEA - much better and no problems! http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html

Comment: Amir, check out my "answer" with steps 1 through 7. You ever find something else that fixed that takes less steps?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a USB 3.0 port too and a device Xoom with ics 4.0.
To solve my problem, I needed to restart my Windows, because in the DDMS my device was showed twice.
After the restart, I needed to change the USB port to a 2.0 USB port and it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused by an USB bug

1- Save your work
2- Close Eclipse
3- Restart your computer
4- Open Eclipse and enjoy ^^

it works for me

Good luck