# DDMS shows Error "cause of devicemonitor failed to start monitoring android"

Tags: android, memory-management, location

My DDMS shows an error when I connect my phone to Eclipse which says "**cause of device monitor failed to start monitoring android**"

Question 1:

What is the cause of this Error?

Question 2

My Application fetches coordinates. After some time, it stops giving me the coordinates, then when I clear the RAM using Task Manager and launch the app again, it will give me coordinates again for a while. How do I configure it so that my application will give the coordinates continuously, OR when memory gets back, it should start fetching coordinates again automatically.

Comment: Take a look at this question.  It speaks to your first issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577596/constantly-getting-devicemonitor-failed-to-start-monitoring

Comment: i have already gone through this tutorial