# Receiving error "DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring" when connecting Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android

I get the error "DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring..." in Eclipse when I connect my Galaxy Nexus to my computer.

I had this working fine at one time.  Since then, all I've done is root the phone.  Could this have screwed something up?

Anyway, I've gone through every possible solution to fix this:

- Reinstalled drivers (before I did this, Eclipse didn't even see the phone at all)
- I loaded a cmd prompt (Windows 7 Ultimate 64) and ran adb kill-server
- I added the Android SDK and tools to the path variable
- Rebooting phone and computer
- Praying

I'm at a loss.  The next thing I'll try is re-install Eclipse.  I really, REALLY don't want to do that and I'm not sure it would work anyways.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just got a Transformer Prime and I'm seeing the same error.  Is this a problem with my computer?

Comment: just a bad idea: did you forget to enable debug mode again after root? does `adb devices` show up your device and you can access your phone using `adb shell` ? if Answer is yes, you could assume that it is an eclipse problem. It would help, if you provide full LogCat Output as well

Comment: Not a bad idea but yes, I did enable "USB debugging."  I do see a device using the command "adb devices".  I get this: "emulator-5554 device".  I can also load adb shell.  Do you have a specific command I should use to see something?  I can see the phone in the following in the Android Device Chooser: Serial Number:016B756E1101801D  AVD Name: N/A    Target: unknown    Debug: <empty>    State: Offline               What worries me is the Target: unknown.  It sees it but can't identify it.

Comment: See this answer solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7622641/8524

Answer (score 8):

Try to use a different USB2.0 port, it works for me. I ran into this problem when I use a USB3.0 port and I connected the device to the USB2.0 port it worked normally. I don't know whether it is a bug... My OS is windows 7 ultimate on a machine with both USB2.0 port and USB3.0 port.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem -
Try to use a different USB port.
From my experience, the USB connections on the PC front are not recommended.